# Как получить класс из переменной и создать новый объект этого класса

Tags: java

Имеется запись вида: `List list;` В абстрактном классе.
В наследниках через конструктор, я его инициализирую. `list = new ArrayList();` или  `list = new LinkedList();`

Далее по коду в абстрактном классе имеется создание новых объектов типа `List`, но будет это `ArrayList` или `LinkedList` будет зависеть от объекта `list` что в начале. Как это реализовать?

Как получить класс из объекта `list` и создать новый объект этого же класса.

Comment: Если у вас список выполняет техническую роль (деталь реализации), то тип должен быть одинаков и нет смысла инициализировать список по-разному в наследниках. Если же это какая-то значимая вещь, которая слишком разная - то надо либо выносить из абстрактного класса в наследники, либо прятать за интефейс, либо использовать дженерики (есть же такое в java, верно?)

Comment: Зачем в абстрактном классе указывать поле List list, и в этом же классе создавать его реализации ArrayList и LinkedList? Не лучше ли эти части кода перенести в соответствующие классы-наследники (там, где в конструкторе создаются реализации этого поля List)?

Comment: 2 A.K  Так я бы и вынес, в наследники но. В абстрактном классе полностью идет вся реализация. Но в моей задаче "Реализация hashmap". В роли корзины должны выступать `ArrayList` и `LinkedList`. А сами корзины я храню в массиве листов `List[]`. Через дженерики не получилось у меня. Ведь при инициализации `new LinkedList` Я не могу взять тип из дженерика.

Comment: Вот если бы вы, показали код, то и разглагольствовать бы не пришлось. На счет того, что нельзя взять тип из дженерика, а как вы его берете или пытались брать, не понятно.

Comment: Мне снова подкидывает в очереди проверок ваш вопрос. Прикладывайте код - вот моя рекомендация.

Comment: пометил вопрос решенным. Помог способ №1. Второй тоже уверен работает, но мне удобнее было так, так как я точно знаю какие могут быть реализации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверить все возможные варианты

```
if (list instanceof ArrayList) {
}

if (list instanceof LinkedList) {
}
```

Comment: Писать `instanceof`, на каждый пук и чих, может быть накладно. Сам по себе этот оператор самый медленный и лучше будет использовать другой подход

Comment: @And да, метод не самый оптимальный, но для общего развития не помешает о нем знать.

Answer (score 1):

```
List newList = null;
try {
   newList = list.getClass().newInstance();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно сделать так:

```
public static boolean is(final Object object, final Class clas) {
    return object.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(clas.getSimpleName());
}

List o = new LinkedList();
System.out.println(is(o, ArrayList.class)); //false
```